# Ruby implementation Win32API get mouse scroll/wheel input

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm trying to use win32api on user32.dll to get mouse wheel input.

I tried the following:

```
@state = Win32API.new('user32','DefWindowProc',['i'],'i')
p @state.call(0x0800)
```

But it keeps returning 0 no matter what I do with my mouse wheel.

I thought something is wrong with my mouse, so I tried to do:

```
@state = Win32API.new('user32','GetKeyState',['L'],'L')
p @state.call(0x01) #left key
p @state.call(0x02) #right key
```

It worked, so I'm not sure what's wrong with the mouse wheel.

Regards

Edit 2/20/2014:
I tried to do the following:

```
GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new('user32','GetForegroundWindow','','i')
DefWindowProc = Win32API.new('user32','DefWindowProc','iiii','i')

DefWindowProc.call(GetActiveWindow.call,
```

Then, I got stuck with the UINT / Message (2nd argument).

Edit 2/20/2014:

I found the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message

Latest revision:

```
GetActiveWindow = Win32API.new('user32','GetForegroundWindow','','i')
DefWindowProc = Win32API.new('user32','DefWindowProc','iiii','i')

#WM_MOUSEWHEEL message 0x020A

DefWindowProc.call(GetActiveWindow.call, 0x020A,
```

Now I just need to figure out the 3rd and 4th argument.

Comment: `DefWindowProc` is the Default Procedure for Window Procedure. Calling it out of the blue makes no sense. Is your application a "graphical" one or a "console" one?

Comment: I would say it's graphical because even if I have the option to show console when I run it, I can't type on the console. The application runs on ruby compiler and it doesn't let user to install extension library, but it has a win32api library and script folder, so I could use them to install the mouse input functionality that I would like to have, but to do that, first I'd need to be able to get the mouse input. I'm able to get the left and right click, but I couldn't get the input for mouse wheel.

Comment: If you choose to NOT show a console, then your application has NO User Interface?

Comment: It's still going to have User Interface.

Comment: @manuell I edited the post. I tried to get the message/UINT, but the windows MSDN for message is very extensive and I'm a bit taken back by the long list. I tried to find mouse wheel, but I couldn't find much.

Comment: You don't understand. Your code is not doing what you think. Please have a look at the fundamentals, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx Messages are sent or posted to a a thread message queues, the message loop then dispatch messages to window procedures. Window procedures use the `DefWindowProc` API when they don't want to process a message. Calling that API from one thread/process with one HWND from another thread/process is non sense. Edit the question: describe what you want to do, with no code.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. I hope the question is clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: @manuell - Are you sure the question should have no code?  Without code, it looks like a "write me the code" question and is liable to be closed because it gives the false  appearance that the OP has made no effort.

Comment: No. I am not sure. I told you so because your code was really out of context. But code shows at least that you tried something. Feel free to add code again. Sorry.

Comment: Reverted and voted reopen. You want to know about mouse wheel events while the mouse pointer is over *another* application?

Comment: My objective is to get the mouse scroll/wheel state, so I don't mind whether the mouse pointer is over another application or the application that I want, as long it reads using the WIN32API. If you could give me solutions for each scenario that would be very helpful for future reference. Haha. Been working on it for 2 days already, kept re-reading the msdn pages over and over, and I still couldn't solve it yet.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know Ruby, I will give here a solution in C/C++ using only standard Win32 APIs. If you can call Win32 APIs from Ruby, that will work.

Note that the solution involves "callback" and "pointer". I know that's possible in Python (for example, with the `ctypes` module) and hope that same thing is possible with Ruby.

1. [Register a Window Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx) and [create a Window from that class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx), the window will be a [Message-Only Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only), so it will be invisible, with no GUI.
2. Use the [RegisterRawInputDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx) API to ask for raw events from mouse devices.
3. Set up a message loop, with the standard `GetMessage`/`DispatchMessage` combo.
4. Process the sent `WM_INPUT` message in your Window Procedure
    4.1. Allocate memory for the raw datas
    4.2. Retrieve the raw datas
    4.3. Filter for mouse event and wheel datas
    4.4. Process (I just print the wheel delta)
    4.5. Free allocated memory.

Below, full source code. Build with VS2012 Express on Windows 7.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

int main( void ) {

    WNDCLASS WndClass;
    memset( &WndClass, 0, sizeof( WndClass ) );
    WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    WndClass.lpszClassName = L"MyRawInputClass";
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc = MyWindowProc;
    RegisterClass( &WndClass );

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( WndClass.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              HWND_MESSAGE, 0, WndClass.hInstance, 0 );

    RAWINPUTDEVICE RawInputDevice;
    RawInputDevice.usUsagePage = 0x01; // Generic Desktop Controls
    RawInputDevice.usUsage = 0x02; // Mouse
    RawInputDevice.dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    RawInputDevice.hwndTarget = hWnd; 
    BOOL bWin32Success = RegisterRawInputDevices( &RawInputDevice, 1,
                                                  static_cast<UINT>( sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) ) );

    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while( ( bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 ) ) != 0 ) {
        if (bRet != -1) {
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }

    // NO GUI, UNREACHABLE
    DestroyWindow( hWnd );
    UnregisterClass( WndClass.lpszClassName, WndClass.hInstance );

    return 0;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {

    switch ( uiMsg ) {

        case WM_INPUT: {
            UINT dwSize;
            HRAWINPUT hRawInput = reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>( lParam );
            UINT uiRetCode = GetRawInputData( hRawInput, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize,
                                              static_cast<UINT>( sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) ) );
            if ( uiRetCode != 0xffffffff ) {
                LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[ dwSize ];
                uiRetCode = GetRawInputData( hRawInput, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize,
                                             static_cast<UINT>( sizeof( RAWINPUTHEADER ) ) );
                if ( uiRetCode > 0 ) {
                    RAWINPUT* praw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>( lpb );
                    if ( praw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE ) {
                        if ( praw->data.mouse.usButtonFlags & RI_MOUSE_WHEEL ) {
                            signed int siDelta = static_cast<SHORT>( praw->data.mouse.usButtonData );
                            printf( "WHEEL EVENT: Delta = %d\n", siDelta );
                        }
                    }
                }
                delete[] lpb;
            }
            break;

        } // WM_INPUT

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good reference!! For C pointer in ruby, we have [link]http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/dl/rdoc/DL/CPtr.html I'll to research about the callback.