# Winforms Rich Textbox allow scrolling when mouse over

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have simple chat application with Rich Textbox to display messages and Textbox to write them. I'd like to have same behaviour as facebook chat does, which is having focus on the Textbox but being able to use mouse wheel to scroll the one I'm hovering over. So as an example: I'm writting something in the Textbox but in the meantime I want to scroll the Rich Textbox upwards by using my mousewheel without loosing focus on the Textbox. Facebook chat has this exact behaviour.

Semi pseudo code I came up with:

```
    private void richTextBox_MouseOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseWheelScroll -> richTextBox scroll, msgTextBox don't scroll
    }
```

Comment: Try simple project with two `RichTextBox`es and you will see that this is default behaviour (scroll control under cursor).

Comment: I just did. Mouse wheel scroll, scrolled the RichTextBox that had focus, not the one that had mouse over.

Comment: So It could depend on user's system (my is Windows 10, .net 4.5)

Comment: I'm interested in the same behaviour..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I confirm Dmitriy Zapevalov's insight, Windows 10 Operative System
  has a new interesting feature:

  > Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them

  This is exactly the behaviour you desire, I can confirm it works both
  in Winform and WPF application and in general it is the behaviour of
  any window I see on my monitor. It is enabled by default, user can
  disable it.
- It is a little bit tricky to reproduce that on c# applications
  running on windows Xp, Vista, 7 or Windows 8, you can find that issue solved in C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570063/how-can-i-detect-mouse-scroll-event-on-windows-from-background-app) and in manuell answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899872/ruby-implementation-win32api-get-mouse-scroll-wheel-input/21961482#21961482)